# PHP DateTime bug with "j/n‏/Y g:i:s a", result is "21/1‏/2016 23:59:59 am"

Tags: php, datetime

Consider the following example:

```
<?php
$localTime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($localTime->format("j/n‏/Y g:i:s a"));
?>
```

The expected behavior is something like: `21/1/2016 23:59:59 am`

But what I get as output is:
`21/1‏/2016 23:59:59 am`

Which is totally unexpected and weird result. It seems that the year is moved after the time part and the date+month are merged with the time (space is ignored).

Note that this only happens if you copy past the above code. If you manually type the `j/n‏/Y g:i:s a` part, the issue is not present.

*Edit: the broken date format is taken deep from within the Yii framework source code (yii/i18n/data/ar.php).*

Comment: What are you talking about? https://3v4l.org/n3u8J   --- EDIT: I copy pasted as you said and then I get this: https://3v4l.org/QStjU meaning you have something done wrong in there?

Comment: Same results as @Naruto.

Comment: Try it in http://phpfiddle.org or locally.

Comment: Yeah, messes up in phpfiddle.

Comment: remove / and add again... / i dont know y, but it will work

Comment: If I copy paste yours it fails like yours, but if I rewrite `j/n/Y` I git the expected value. I'm guessing you have some corrupt characters lurking in your formatting string, UTF8 ghosts

Comment: Copy&paste results in this for me: `string(22) "22/1./2016 10:14:36 am"`

Answer (score 2):

Peculiar for sure - I would guess it's something to do with character set.

```
$p1='j/n‏/Y g:i:s a';/* pasted */
$p2='j/n/Y g:i:s a';/* manually typed */


$localTime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump( $localTime->format($p1) );
echo '<br />';
var_dump( $localTime->format($p2) );

echo '<br />'.( $p1===$p2 ? 'same' : 'different' );
```

### output:

```
string(24) "22/1‏/2016 10:13:51 am"
string(21) "22/1/2016 10:13:51 am"
different 

for( $i=0; $i < strlen( $p1 ); $i++ ){
    echo ord( substr( $p1,$i,1 ) ). '  '.ord( substr( $p2,$i,1 ) ).BR;  
}
```

This shows that the slash `/` is different and others too.

Comment: I confirm RamRaider's observations re. pasting / manually entering. When i convert the pasted text from UTF8 to ANSII I see an extra character after the second "/". Removing this extra character gives the correct result - also when re-converted to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments above, if you write `(/)` slashes manually it will work.

```
$localTime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($localTime->format("j/n/Y g:i:s a"));
```

**Result:**

```
string(22) "22/1/2016 10:18:25 am"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling around in my console...

```
// copy-paste of input
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".length
> 14

// manual typing
"j/n/Y g:i:s a".length
> 13
```

Huh.

Bit of digging...

```
// pasted input
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".charAt(0)
> "j"
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".charAt(1)
> "/"
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".charAt(2)
> "n"
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".charAt(3)
> "‏"
```

Hmm.

```
// pasted input
"j/n‏/Y g:i:s a".charCodeAt(3).toString(16)
> "200f"
```

U+200F is the Right-to-Left marker. Remove it and the problem is solved.

[image: Not sure if troll]

Answer (score 0):

You have invisible character after your `n`. Copy and paste to Notepad++, and change encoding to ANSI, you will see:

`var_dump($localTime->format("j/nâ€Ź/Y g:i:s a"));`

Just remove it with backspace and it is OK.